# 2D Grid probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a 2D grid, how many distinct paths are there from (0, 0) to (x, y) that follow the gridlines and move only up and to the right. Provide your reasoning.

Would the number of combinations simply be x * y? Or would it be something with powers and factorials?

Comment: try examples! What are the answers when $x$ and $y$ are between $1$ and $3$? Make a table. Then see the pattern.

Comment: Then you can check if your guess, $x \cdot y$, is valid on the table of examples, rather than just guessing at random and hoping it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider s $2x2$ grid. Count the number of ways you can end up at $(2,2)$. You should get that there are $6$ different ways.

In this particular case, you have $4$ moves to make. $2$ moves must be to the right and $2$ must be up. Thus there are ${4\choose{2}}=6$ combinations.

Also consider a $3x2$ grid. You should find that there are $10$ different ways.

In this case, you have $5$ moves to make, where $3$ moves must be to the right and $2$ must be up. Thus there are ${5\choose{2}}=10$ combinations.

In general, for a grid of $(x,y)$, there are $${{x+y}\choose{x}}={{x+y}\choose{y}}={\frac{(x+y)!}{x!\cdot y!}}$$ different combinations.